# How to set textbox values while clicking on grid using javascript function

Tags: javascript, textbox

I want to set textbox values while clicking on dojoGrid. On dojoGrid's click event I wrote java function.Want to set textbox values same as selected item of grid. Below is my JavaScript function.

```
dojoGrid1Click: function(inSender, evt, selectedItem, rowId, fieldId, rowNode, cellNode) {
try {
       alert("selected item value="+inSender.dataSet.getItem(evt.rowIndex).getData().name);

       document.getElementById("txtName").value=(inSender.dataSet.getItem(evt.rowIndex).getData().name);

} catch(e) {
  console.error('ERROR IN dojoGrid1Click: ' + e);
}
},
```

I can see the selected item in alert.But why this cant be set to the textbox? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think you should remove brackets:

```
  document.getElementById("txtName").value=(inSender.dataSet.getItem(evt.rowIndex).getData().name);
```

to

```
document.getElementById("txtName").value=inSender.dataSet.getItem(evt.rowIndex).getData().name;
```

Usually when brackets are set in this way mean that returns a boolean in assignment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But I've removed brackets,its still not working.

Comment: then the only thing that can be is that the element with id txtName do not exists or there are more that one elements with id txtName (id must be unique).